# Как закрыть statemant с помощью try-with-resorces?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public void dropUsersTable() {
    String SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user";
    try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
        statement.close();
        System.out.println("Table delete");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкции try-with-resources можно открывать несколько ресурсов, перечисляя их через точку с запятой:

```
public void dropUsersTable() {
    String SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user";
    try (Connection connection = getConnection();
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement())
    {
        statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
        System.out.println("Table delete");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В приведённом выше коде закроется и `statement`, и `connection`, что абсолютно корректно.

Теоретически, переменную `connection` можно не объявлять:

```
public void dropUsersTable() {
    String SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user";
    try (Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement())
    {
        statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
        System.out.println("Table delete");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Однако в таком случае `statement` хоть и закроется, но останется открытым соединение к базе данных, что очень нежелательно. Поэтому лучше использовать первый вариант кода.

Comment: а если не создавать отдельную переменную для Connection, он закроется?

Comment: Проверил - не закроется. Спасибо за замечание, исправил ответ. @Евгений Шевченко